# Meaning of “hoodwink” in a 1796 passage

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

Maybe someone is able to paraphrase and/or make sense of the following, from the 1796 *[Narrative of W. Spavens, Chatham Pensioner, Written by Himself](https://books.google.com/books?id=g_heAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA124&lpg=PA124)*:

> As to the matter of serving, it is this — they give a man liberty to choose a piece [of meat] for his mess, and then hoodwink him, and when the Steward calls a mess, he touches a piece, and the Cook give it to the man it is for, and he touches again.

None of the definitions of *hoodwink* I found seems to fit here. And what about *and he touches again*?

Comment: Please tell us where that quote is from.

Comment: Also tell us what definitions of 'hoodwink' you found and why you think they don't fit here. Meanwhile I'm voting to close this Q. for this reason "**Please include the research you've done**, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from [The Narrative of W. Spavens, Chatham Pensioner](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=g_heAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA124&lpg=PA124&dq=steward%20calls%20a%20mess%20and%20he%20touches%20a%20piece&source=bl&ots=aPzZmnTzAB&sig=s6h4cuQx5YUuUNSxKrlcQrRwECU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYjcu8uN3SAhXmA8AKHUMECjAQ6AEIGTAB#v=onepage&q=steward%20calls%20a%20mess%20and%20he%20touches%20a%20piece&f=false) and is describing the way meals are served on board ship. The preceding text describes how the order of calling people for meals is changed around in the interests of fairness, mess shifts are changed regularly and the order of calling is reversed each day. This gives us the clue to understanding the passage in question. It is a method of avoiding favouritism, or its appearance, in serving food.

So this section

> "As to the matter of serving, it is this - they give a man liberty to
>   choose a piece [of meat] for his mess, and then hoodwink him, and when
>   the Steward calls a mess, he touches a piece, and the Cook give it to
>   the man it is for, and he touches again."

can be understood to mean:

At each meal one man is chosen. He selects his own portion of meat (which is set aside for him to eat later, or he eats before the rest, the text doesn't specify). He is then blindfolded. In this condition he selects, by touching, the portion for the next man to be served. The Cook serves that portion and the man selecting touches again to indicate the portion for the next man.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was not aware of the whole process of one man being blindfolded to chose the pieces for the others... Makes perfect sense now.

Comment: Well, nor was I until I looked at your quote in context. It is almost always worth including a wider quote than the bit you are stuck with. Both before and after your sentence the text is about randomising food servings, you have to apply that context. Can i recommend you go back and edit your question to give a link to the book and include more text?